# AWS setup cloud infrastructure for Java Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Well, I want to know the basic of cloud infrastructure for Amazon cloud.

Can anyone help me how I can move ahead with this? and what would be the best for me?

Below mentioned is my requirement:

**Project:** Java EE based architecture

**Deployment Server:** Tomcat

**DataBase:** MySQL

**Instance:** Amazon ec2 and AWS Elastic Beanstalk (However I'm not sure what is
good for Java related project)

**Space:** 100 GB for now and it should be salable on the based on instant requirement.

**Hosting Server:** Linux

Here I want to know every possible things which can be good for initial setup for my production server.

Also, I would like to know what are the services that I need to purchase based on my requirement, and suggest me for the same, also guide me the best prices as well for the specific service.

Looking forward to hear from you everyone guys,

Have a nice time ahead!

Kuldeep

Comment: Without knowing what you your project is doing it is impossible to make recommendations about the requisite infrastructure.

Comment: Sourav Gulati gave me the good suggestions, so I'm good with that for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to start with Amazon EC2. For mysql, you can use Amazon RDS as well as it handles all the maintenance activity for DB. Also, you can start with m3.xl machines initially and can upgrade based on requirement.

As per storage is concerned, start with 100GB SSD EBS first . You can anytime attach more storage as needed.
Here are some useful links regarding machine types and costing:
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_SG&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=ec2_b&sc_content=sitelink&sc_detail=ec2%20instance&sc_category=ec2&sc_segment=instance_types&sc_matchtype=p&sc_country=SG&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!154807442051!p!!g!!ec2%20instance&ef_id=WG8jbAAAAIccH41L:20170703093155:s

https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: Thank You, Sourav, which make sense to me for now.. Will be in touch for you for additional help on AWS.

Comment: Sure you can :)